# PHP script to Increment value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to design a scoreboard for a project for my local youth club and would like to be able to click a button onto a wordpress page that will run a PHP script to update a value by 1 in a sql db table, then i can grab the value and display it else where.

Not too worried about passwords being used in scripts at this will only be used within the local network that nobody else has access to, have looked around and found a few bits of code but im not able to actually get it working, here's what i've got so far.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "sot";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = UPDATE wp_sotstats SET CaptainChest=CaptainChest+1 WHERE id=1

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The database name is 'sot' the table i want to update is called 'wp_sotstats' and the field within the table is 'CaptainChest' i only need this to really work with just the one entry which the id is '1'

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your $sql string should be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = UPDATE wp_sotstats SET CaptainChest=CaptainChest+1 WHERE id=1

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
```

Is not creating record, it updating it. For me, I will take current value from database as Select, then do ++ to it and do Update query.

```
$sql = UPDATE wp_sotstats SET CaptainChest=CaptainChest+1 WHERE id=1
```

Please wrap it in quotes and finish statement with semicolon

Comment: On heavily loaded sites, pulling the value, then incrementing it in php, then updating the database can and WILL cause conflicts and increments lost. Trust me on that one ;) Doing `CaptainChest=CaptainChest+1` is the better way.

Comment: @IncredibleHat
"Not too worried about passwords being used in scripts at this will only be used within the local network that nobody else has access to, have looked around and found a few bits of code but im not able to actually get it working, here's what i've got so far." quote is saying that local network, nobody else)

Comment: I've added quotes into various parts of the string from looking at other examples, but when i come to test the .php file it still just gives me a HTTP ERROR 500, I'm quite a newbie when it comes to SQL so im not sure if the string ive put together is even correct.

Comment: SQL is correct. Try to put in top of the file ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); And look at error, HTTP ERROR 500 is not enough to see a problem for you. And show how you wrap sql query with quotes please

Comment: Just a suggestion and my point of view, not the recommendations to follow)

Comment: Thanks @Alex, So i added the ini_set bit, still just shows the 500 error within chrome.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE wp_sotstats SET CaptainChest=CaptainChest+1 WHERE id=1";
Don't forget semicolons

Comment: @Alex, i've just replaced that line into the file and it works now :D, Really appreciate the help, it was starting to send me nuts